# How to check Drop date time of an ORACLE view

Tags: oracle11g

Where can I see at what time a view was dropped from database.

For other object types such as Indexes and tables , I use dba_recyclebin to check the droptime , but for a view I do not think that ORACLE captures details in this table.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to know if the view was dropped? Type `select count(*) from [view_name]` - if the view doesn't exist, Oracle will tell you. There are many other ways - you can query `user_views` or ......

Comment: I wanted to check at what time-stamp a view was dropped.Since it is not stored in DBA_RECYCLEBIN ,  I was wondering if there is some other table where such History is stored. For now it seems that there is no option other than searching archived logs .

Comment: Understood, but please re-read what you wrote (the exact words, not what you "meant" to say) and see if that's the normal interpretation. You said you have trouble in establishing if a view was dropped; you didn't say you KNOW it was dropped and you just want to know when. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the drop was recent enough that the data is still present in your `UNDO` tablespace (likely a few hours but up to a few days depending on your workload and configuration) you should be able to use a flashback query on `dba_views`.  You'd need to have the `FLASHBACK ANY TABLE` privilege.

```
SELECT text
  FROM dba_views AS OF TIMESTAMP( systimestamp - interval '1' hour )
 WHERE owner = <<owner of view>>
   AND view_name = <<name of view>>
```

Beyond that, you could look at your archived logs using `dbms_logmnr` to look for `drop view` statements over a longer time fram.  That is likely to be more effort, however.

Comment: Thanks for the help. dbms_logmnr will do the trick. I was wondering if there was any DBA_RECYCLEBIN equivalant table.